# Editing XML file in a Java program (Android Studio) with info from a dynamically created array

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making an android app (java) where I need to edit an XML file with different routes. I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to edit an XML file with values of a dynamically created array?

So I have a String array named ROUTES[], that gets an updated list of routes from my database.

I need to add that data into a XML file in the following format:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Route Maps</string>
<string name="title_activity_maps">Map</string>
<string name="pickUpButtonText">Need a lift</string>
<string name="choose_route">Route 1</string>
<string-array name="routes">
    <item>Route 2</item>
    <item>Route 3</item>
    <item>Route 4</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

The XML above is used to generate a spinner in android so user can select which route they want to see. Routes can be edited and added, hence why I need to dynamically add the values from ROUTES[] array.

Any suggestions the best and easiest way to do this?

Also how would I reference this XML file (that is in the project) in Java? Would I give relative path or absolute path?

Comment: Bear in mind, that you'll only be able to read this file, not write to it. Because from your task I got an impression that you are going to update it as well.

Comment: XML file is read-only file on Android. You can't edit it. A solution for you is create an array variable in Java.

Comment: You cannot change the xml files that are part of your apk at runtime, but you are perfectly able to create and store xml files in your private storage or in the external storage if you hold that permission - the question is if files stored there, rather than in your apk, will accomplish your need.  Most of what you can do with an xml file in your apk can be accomplished at runtime by other means.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way here would be likely to setup the spinner in your activity and then add these variables to a list of strings and then add this list to a data adapter and then set the spinner this adapter.  This way you can keep updating the values easily.